# Jquery - click to edit script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of data where users can edit the information by a click. The click will replace the number data with an input text field that will allow the users to submit their edits. I've included a "cancel" link where once clicked, the input field will disappear and the data text reappears. However, if I clicked to edit multiple rows and cancel it, the data text will reappear as the first row that I clicked.

For example, my table of data looks like this

```
Ref No.  |  Container No.
0006     |  OLKI2940
0005     |  KL2223KL
0004     |  PPO80596
0003     |  JLJ93459
```

If I clicked to edit Container # "OLKI2940", I cancel it and "OLKI2940" will reappear fine. However, if I clicked to edit the second row Container # "KL2223KL" and cancel, the Container # "OLKI2940" will appear. So it's copying the first row that I clicked. How do I get it for the right container number to appear?

My html as follow:

```
// this is in a loop
<tr>
   <td>{{ refnum }}</td>
   <td id="{{ ctrnum }}"><a href="#" class="ctrnoedit">{{ ctrnum }}</a></td>
</tr>
```

My JS:

```
// editing container no
   $('#containers').delegate("a.ctrnoedit","click", function() {
      var index = $(this).closest("td").attr("id");
      var html = "<form id='editctrno' method='post'><input name='ctrnum' type='text' value='"+index+"'>" +
    "<br><button type='submit'>Update</button> <a href='#' id='canceledit'>Cancel</a></form>";
      $(this).closest("td").html(html);

    $('#containers').delegate("a#canceledit", "click", function() {
         $(this).closest("#editctrno").html("<a href='#' class='ctrnoedit'>"+index+"</a>");
    })
})
```

JS fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9Lsgw2ve/1/

Comment: For what it's worth, [X-editable](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x-editable/info) and [Jeditable](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jeditable/info) are just two of the plugins that provide this exact inline-edit functionality.

Comment: @Blazemonger - yes I know, I kind of just want to make a simple one of my own.

Comment: it seems like the id `"#editctrno"` is duplicated, therefore it will always return the first matched element. ids must be unique, use class instead

Comment: @AminJafari - it is still giving me the same results.

Comment: It might help to have a demo. Here's a start. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9Lsgw2ve/

Comment: Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/9Lsgw2ve/1/, it doesn't work with .on(), but will with .delegate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although your way of coding violates the rules of html by generating duplicated ids, this is a **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lsgw2ve/2/)**

```
var index='';
// editing container no
$('#containers').delegate("a.ctrnoedit", "click", function () {
    index = $(this).closest("td").attr("id");
    var html = "<form id='editctrno' method='post'><input name='ctrnum' type='text' value='" + index + "'>" +
        "<br><button type='submit'>Update</button> <a href='#' id='canceledit'>Cancel</a></form>";
    $(this).closest("td").html(html);

    $('#containers').delegate("a#canceledit", "click", function () {
        $(this).closest("#editctrno").html("<a href='#' class='ctrnoedit'>" + index + "</a>");
    })
})
```

you just need to define `index` out of the `click` function

also if you wanna get the exact same values as it was in the links then try this:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lsgw2ve/4/)**

```
var index='';
// editing container no
$('#containers').delegate("a.ctrnoedit", "click", function () {
    index = $(this).closest("td").children('a').html();
    var html = "<form id='editctrno' method='post'><input name='ctrnum' type='text' value='" + index + "'>" +
        "<br><button type='submit'>Update</button> <a href='#' id='canceledit'>Cancel</a></form>";
    $(this).closest("td").html(html);

    $('#containers').delegate("a#canceledit", "click", function () {
        $(this).closest("#editctrno").html("<a href='#' class='ctrnoedit'>" + index + "</a>");
    })
})
```

Comment: works like a charm! Does defining the index out of the click function help it recycle to an empty variable each time?

Comment: no, it makes it a global variable! it means whenever and wherever you change its value, it's gonna be affected and changed immediately